# cannot send mails with my mail() function: get DNS error

Tags: linux, debian, sendmail

I am using php mail() function and I do not reveive any emails: 
(debian, sendmail)

Here is the mail.log

```
Jan 26 18:00:37 sd-45956 sendmail[3918]: s0QH0bRO003918: from=www-data, size=116, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401261700.s0QH0bRO003918@haveameet.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Jan 26 18:00:37 sd-45956 sm-mta[3919]: s0QH0bOw003919: from=<www-data@haveameet.com>, size=379, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401261700.s0QH0bRO003918@haveameet.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=haveameet.com [127.0.0.1]
Jan 26 18:00:37 sd-45956 sendmail[3918]: s0QH0bRO003918: to=yarekc@laposte.net, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30116, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s0QH0bOw003919 Message accepted for delivery)
Jan 26 18:00:38 sd-45956 sm-mta[3921]: s0QH0bOw003919: to=<yarekc@laposte.net>, ctladdr=<www-data@haveameet.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120379, relay=smtp4.laposte.net. [193.251.214.113], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error
Jan 26 18:00:38 sd-45956 sm-mta[3921]: s0QH0bOw003919: s0QH0cOw003921: DSN: Data format error
Jan 26 18:00:38 sd-45956 sm-mta[3921]: s0QH0cOw003921: to=<www-data@haveameet.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

ANy idea how to solve that ?
I tried to mess with  /etc/hosts
but did not help

I tried to change /etc/hosts

to 127.0.0.1       haveameet.com

and now I am given:

```
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sendmail[5642]: s0QJ9XXK005642: from=www-data, size=116, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401261909.s0QJ9XXK005642@62-210-238-225.online.net>, relay=www-data@localhost
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sm-mta[5643]: s0QJ9Xpd005643: ruleset=check_rcpt, arg1=<yarekc@laposte.net>, relay=haveameet.com [127.0.0.1], reject=553 5.1.8 <yarekc@laposte.net>... Domain of sender address www-data@62-210-238-225.online.net does not exist
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sendmail[5642]: s0QJ9XXK005642: to=yarekc@laposte.net, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30116, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.8, stat=User unknown
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sm-mta[5643]: s0QJ9Xpd005643: from=<www-data@62-210-238-225.online.net>, size=116, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=haveameet.com [127.0.0.1]
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sendmail[5642]: s0QJ9XXK005642: s0QJ9XXL005642: DSN: User unknown
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sm-mta[5643]: s0QJ9Xpf005643: from=<>, size=2340, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401261909.s0QJ9XXL005642@62-210-238-225.online.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=haveameet.com [127.0.0.1]
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sendmail[5642]: s0QJ9XXL005642: to=www-data, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31140, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s0QJ9Xpf005643 Message accepted for delivery)
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sm-mta[5645]: s0QJ9Xpf005643: to=<www-data@62-210-238-225.online.net>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=122340, relay=62-210-238-225.online.net, dsn=5.1.2, stat=Host unknown (Name server: 62-210-238-225.online.net: host not $
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sm-mta[5645]: s0QJ9Xpf005643: s0QJ9Xpd005645: postmaster notify: Host unknown (Name server: 62-210-238-225.online.net: host not found)
Jan 26 20:09:33 sd-45956 sm-mta[5645]: s0QJ9Xpd005645: to=bourlier, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

It says 'DSN' error, not 'DNS'.

Change `/etc/hostname` to something other than `localhost`. The mail server you are connecting to doesn't like the name of your machine.

Comment: You can clearly see in his log that the machine name is _not_ `localhost`. But it is probably also not a valid hostname.

Comment: I did that: changed to 127.0.0.1 haveameet.com and I am given another error: DSN: User unknown